# Is it possible to export SVG 2D animation as path using Blender?

Tags: animation, export, svg

Hi everybody I am new to blender,

I have seen [this animation](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/984446517b98d5cf3ff14c746326055d41802084/68747470733a2f2f7261776769746875622e636f6d2f68766672616e636573636f2f667265657374796c657376672f6d61737465722f6578616d706c652f6d696b75352e737667)

I would know if Blender is capable to export this kind of file as SVG path using Grease pencil or other mean?
Also when I am downloading the file the SVG size is 4.6MO, I would export the path of the file to limitate the amount of memory necessary to implement the file in my webpage. How please can I do that?

thanks

Comment: Blender is more than capable. Would be a simplish script to knock together.  Looked into it after finding  this cool animated svg http://tavmjong.free.fr/blog/wp-content/uploads/BATMAN/batman_logos.svg  _to blatantly steal for an icon_ from http://tavmjong.free.fr/blog/?p=741 It explains the data stucture used.  , mulled around the idea of extending the svg importer to read and create  animations  Thought bubbled the idea of using a frame change handler to swap in the curve data, In the end i used a text editor to grep out  each shape.  Agree too would be an ideal way to export gp animations.